# Symfony Sonata Admin Bundle 500 Error

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I got a problem using the Symfony Sonata Admin Bundle. 
I got two entities. Faq and FaqCategory.

A Faq entry relates to one FaqCategory and one FaqCategory entry relates to many Faq entires. SO a OneToMany Relation.
(You can find the code here: https://gist.github.com/dominikkukacka/5866741).

Every time I try creating a new FAQ I get an Error:

```
Class does not exist 500 Internal Server Error - ReflectionException`
```

Has this something to do with my relations or am I missing someting?

Thanks in advance!

Dominik